# How can I remove the padding and center this element?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've been trying to center and remove the bottom-padding of the 'filter' image for a couple hours now but can't seem to do it. It's probably a really simple fix, but I'm pretty new to CSS, HTML and flexbox and the solution has escaped me so far! If someone could point me in the right direction, that would be awesome.

[image: Screenshot]

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'/>
    <title>Some Web Page</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='styles.css'/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class='menu-container'>
      <div class='menu'>
        <div class='links'>
          <div class='signup'>Sign Up</div>
          <div class='login'>Login</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='header-container'>
      <div class='header'>
      </div>
    </div>
    <main>
      <input id="toggle" type="checkbox">
      <label for="toggle">
          <div class="filterbutton"><img src='images/filterbutton.svg'/></div>
      </label>
      <div id="expand">
        <section class="Filter">
        </section>
      </div>
    </main>
    <section class="carousel">
    </section>
  </body>
  <footer>
      <img src="images/facebook.svg" alt="facebook" title="facebook" href="#" class="social">
      <img src="images/twitter.svg" alt="twitter" title="twitter" href="#" class="social">
      <img src="images/instagram.svg" alt="instagram" title="instagram" href="#" class="social">
      <img src="images/snapchat.svg" alt="snapchat" title="snapchat" href="#" class="social">
      <ul>
          <a alt="about" title="About" href="#" class="footerlink">About</a>
          <a alt="about" title="About" href="#" class="footerlink">Contact</a>
          <a alt="about" title="About" href="#" class="footerlink">Team</a>
          <a alt="about" title="About" href="#" class="footerlink">Whatever</a>
      </ul>
  </footer>
</html>
```

CSS

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.button {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.menu-container {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #A34F43;
  padding: 20px 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.menu {
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.links {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.login {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.header-container {
  background-color: #FF7C69;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.carousel-test {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.carousel-grid-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.carousel-grid {
  width: 900px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.logo {
  width: 200px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700);

body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", Arial;
  width: 100%;
}
main {
  background: #FF7C69;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

input {
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
}
label {
  /* display: block; */
  /* text-align: center; */
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 50%;
}
label:hover {
  color: #000;
}

#expand {
  height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: height 0.3s;
  background-color: #D6DBED;
  color: #FFF;
}

#toggle:checked ~ #expand {
  height: 250px;
}

footer {
  background-color: #A34F43;
  text-align: right;
  color: #eee;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%; 
  /* display: flex; */
}

.footerlink {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  text-align: justify;
  display: block;
  padding: 1px;
}

.social {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 50px;
  text-align: right;
  float: right;
}

.social:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

legend {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 3px 6px;
}

.output {
  font: 1rem 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
}

input {
  margin: .4rem;
}

.filterbutton {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 150px;
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: change label width from `50%` to the size of image for example `100px`

Comment: Thanks, that did it! Can you tell me why it works that way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to ur css

```
.filterbutton img{
    display: block;
}
```

---

`img` tags have little space below them

The above css will remove the space below the img tag by making the image `display: block;` , which is `display:inline` by default.

The space you are seeing is for descenders. This space is kept for characters like "y" ,"p".

As for the centering of the label, width:50%, means the parent will try to center the entire container(50% width), that is y, the label didnt look centered.

Add width to label, to center it

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700);
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.button {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.menu-container {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #A34F43;
  padding: 20px 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.menu {
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.links {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.login {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.header-container {
  background-color: #FF7C69;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.carousel-test {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.carousel-grid-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.carousel-grid {
  width: 900px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.logo {
  width: 200px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", Arial;
  width: 100%;
}

main {
  background: #FF7C69;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

input {
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
}

label {
  /* display: block; */
  /* text-align: center; */
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
 width: 100px;
}

label:hover {
  color: #000;
}

#expand {
  height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: height 0.3s;
  background-color: #D6DBED;
  color: #FFF;
}

#toggle:checked~#expand {
  height: 250px;
}

footer {
  background-color: #A34F43;
  text-align: right;
  color: #eee;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  /* display: flex; */
}

.footerlink {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  text-align: justify;
  display: block;
  padding: 1px;
}

.social {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 50px;
  text-align: right;
  float: right;
}

.social:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

legend {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 3px 6px;
}

.output {
  font: 1rem 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
}

input {
  margin: .4rem;
}

.filterbutton {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 150px;
  display: block;
}

.filterbutton img{
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class='menu-container'>
  <div class='menu'>
    <div class='links'>
      <div class='signup'>Sign Up</div>
      <div class='login'>Login</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class='header-container'>
  <div class='header'>
  </div>
</div>
<main>
  <input id="toggle" type="checkbox">
  <label for="toggle">
          <div class="filterbutton"><img src='https://placehold.it/100x100'/></div>
      </label>
  <div id="expand">
    <section class="Filter">
    </section>
  </div>
</main>
<section class="carousel">
</section>

<footer>
  <img src="images/facebook.svg" alt="facebook" title="facebook" href="#" class="social">
  <img src="images/twitter.svg" alt="twitter" title="twitter" href="#" class="social">
  <img src="images/instagram.svg" alt="instagram" title="instagram" href="#" class="social">
  <img src="images/snapchat.svg" alt="snapchat" title="snapchat" href="#" class="social">
  <ul>
    <a alt="about" title="About" href="#" class="footerlink">About</a>
    <a alt="about" title="About" href="#" class="footerlink">Contact</a>
    <a alt="about" title="About" href="#" class="footerlink">Team</a>
    <a alt="about" title="About" href="#" class="footerlink">Whatever</a>
  </ul>
</footer>
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize that was the default :)

Comment: @LouisGridleyWu, if this anwer helped you then please accept it